# How to return angular 5 view in laravel view() helper function?

Tags: angular, laravel, angular5, laravel-5.4, reset-password

> I am using angular 5 for frontend and laravel 5.4 for backend. Now i
>   am getting stuck  when creating reset password module. because my view
>   is coming with angular components. I am using laravel's default reset
>   password functions.
>
> When i clicked on reset password link from mail i want to go with
>   angular view rather than laravel's default `auth\passwords\reset`.

I already create one angular form for this but not undestanding how to connect with laravel and angular.

below is my route for reset password:

```
Route::get('reset_password/{token}','Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
```

controller and method :

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {   
        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }
```

As u see above view of laravel. i want to replace this view with my angular view. i tried with this but failed.  `return view('auth\reset_password.component');`

Is there any simple way for reset password in laravel with angular.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused in how angular should be used. Angular as a framework has a built in router. So you should not use the Laravel router to do the routing. That should be taken care of by the Angular router instead. When you route to for example the reset_password/:token page, you should use a resolver to fetch any required data from your Laravel driven REST API. If you do use Laravel router, you will end up with the entire application being reloaded every route change. This would be fine with a small JavaScript library like vue.js or react as you can use it as small additions to your existing Laravel application, this is not the case with angular. It's meant to create complete single page applications. If you do want to use angular as addition to your existing Laravel application, you should dive into a sub project called "Angular Elements". Maybe that could serve your purpose.